# Could someone explain this quicksort implementation in python?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, quicksort

This quicksort implementation I got from Python Cookbook, 2nd Edition. Section 5.11.

```
def qsort(L):
     if not L: return L
     pivot = L[0]
     def lt(x): return x<pivot
     def ge(x): return x>=pivot
     return qsort(filter(lt, L[1:]))+[pivot]+qsort(filter(ge, L[1:]))
```

But I have not managed to completely understand it and the book did not explain in details how it work. Specially this line:

```
return qsort(filter(lt, L[1:]))+[pivot]+qsort(filter(ge, L[1:]))
```

By the way, I know what recursion and quicksort are.

Comment: You want to understand the filter function. Is it?

Comment: Yes, I want to understand this recursive filter.

Answer (score 1):

**filter** takes a function and an iterable and returns a list of the elements of the iterable that cause the function to output **True**. So,

```
return qsort(filter(lt, L[1:]))+[pivot]+qsort(filter(ge, L[1:]))
```

returns a list containing the sorted elements that are less than the pivot, then the pivot, then the sorted elements that are greater than or equal to the pivot.

Comment: You should add the fact that this is a recursive function.

Comment: I was taking the OP at their word that they know what recursion is, but that is potentially an improvement.

Comment: This code will execute until there is only one sorted element in the list?

Answer (score 0):

Added some comments

```
 def qsort(L):
     if not L: return L #stop condition
     pivot = L[0]  #select a pivot! (the first one in the list)
     #create two functions - greater-equal, less-than
     def lt(x): return x<pivot
     def ge(x): return x>=pivot
     #now the magic - split the list via the pivot and quick sort the sub lists
     return qsort(filter(lt, L[1:])) + # sort all elements smaller than pivot
                 [pivot] +   #the pivot
                  qsort(filter(ge, L[1:])) # sort all elements greater-equal then pivot 

     #the with only filter on L[1:] because we don't want the pivot itself (we found it by using L[0]...)
```

Comment: if not L: return L also verifies if list is empty from the  beginning

Comment: @minitoto - Thats a private case of the stop condition I guess